# How do I show screen when using tabbar navigation? React-Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

When I navigate to my `FeedScreen`, it only shows a white background. However my `FeedScreen` contains a background image and buttons etc. Does anyone know why I am only getting a white screen? My navigation consists of my `MainTabNav`, which is tabbar holding three tabs, one of which is `DiscoverNav`, which is another TabBar, that should show two different screens, however it is only showing a white background. Thanks! BTW, I am using React-Navigation for navigation! Thanks!

```
const DiscoverNav = TabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: FeedScreen
  },
  Dank: {
    screen: DankScreen
  },
  //Add in more tabs here
},
{
  tabBarPosition: 'top'
});


const TicketNav = TabNavigator({
  Tickets: {
    screen: TicketScreen
  },
  History: {
    screen: HistoryScreen
  },
  //Add in more tabs here
},
{
  tabBarPosition: 'top'
});

const MainTabNav = TabNavigator({
  Discover: {
    screen: DiscoverNav
  },
  Tickets: {
    screen: TicketNav
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: FeedScreen
  }
},
{
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
});
```